# Mac Terminal File Rename Randomly

Tags: mac, terminal, batch-file

What is the best way to rename files for example `.JPG` & `.jpg` at the same time.

I have looked on here and google and come across things like below but is there a way to cover both?

**Script:**

```
for i in *.jpg; do mv -i "$i" ${RANDOM}${RANDOM}.jpg; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set filename expansion to insensitive:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
```

And then your script machtes both: *.jpg and *.JPG:

```
for i in *.jpg; echo $i; done
file.jpg
file.JPG
file.Jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can put both commands mentioned below in a file with extension .sh like image_change.sh and execute from command line sh image_change.sh

```
for i in *.jpg; do mv -i "$i" ${RANDOM}${RANDOM}.jpg; done;
for i in *.JPG; do mv -i "$i" ${RANDOM}${RANDOM}.jpg; done;
```